# JMeter Maven Distributed - Immediate Shutdown with 0 Results

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, azure-aks, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am developing a JMeter dynamic master-slaves Performance Environment with the help of Azure Kubernetes, Jenkins, Helm, JMeter Java Plugin V3.0.0, JMeter version 5.2.1 . Jnlp, Maven and Helm are running inside a Jenkins Agent while the JMeter Slaves are spawned up as Kubernetes Deployment Pods. During the execution both the JMeter Master, Slave nodes are spawning and it will start the slave agents successfully as well. But after some time, I see it's shutting down immediately with 0 results.

I have tried disabling the Distributed Jmeter Slaves and it is working fine without any issue when executing only from the Master. Please help me to find out the issue with the slave configs

**pom.xml File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <name>Performance Setup Onboard</name>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>perf-onboard</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <jmeter.version>5.2.1</jmeter.version>
        <jmeter.maven.plugin.version>3.0.0</jmeter.maven.plugin.version>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <!--<timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>-->
        <jmeter.directory>${basedir}/target/jmeter</jmeter.directory>
        <jmeter.dashboard.dir>${jmeter.directory}/results/html</jmeter.dashboard.dir>
        <report.generation>true</report.generation>
        <jmxFile>testDemoScript</jmxFile>
        <jenkinsSlaveNodes>1</jenkinsSlaveNodes>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-test-data-1</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${jmeter.directory}/testFiles/data</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>./src/test/data</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>*.csv</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jmeter.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>configuration</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>configure</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>results</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmeter-plugins-extras-libs</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <testFilesIncluded>
                        <jMeterTestFile>${jmxFile}.jmx</jMeterTestFile>
                    </testFilesIncluded>
                    <resultsFileNameDateFormat>${maven.build.timestamp.format}</resultsFileNameDateFormat>
                    <jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
                        <xms>1024</xms>
                        <xmx>1024</xmx>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>-Xprof</argument>
                            <argument>-Xfuture</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
                    <ignoreResultFailures>true</ignoreResultFailures>
                    <remoteConfig>
                        <startServersBeforeTests>true</startServersBeforeTests>
                        <!--<stopServersAfterTests>false</stopServersAfterTests>-->
                        <serverList>${jenkinsSlaveNodes}</serverList>
                    </remoteConfig>
                    <propertiesJMeter>
                        <client.rmi.localport>1099</client.rmi.localport>
                        <!--<https.socket.protocols>TLSv1.2</https.socket.protocols>-->
                    </propertiesJMeter>
                    <propertiesUser>
                        <server.rmi.ssl.disable>true</server.rmi.ssl.disable>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format>csv</jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format>
                    </propertiesUser>
                    <generateReports>${report.generation}</generateReports>
                    <propertiesGlobal>
                        <!--You can define your Customer JMeter Parameters if available-->
                        <protocol>${protocol}</protocol>
                        <host>${host}</host>
                        <basePath>${basePath}</basePath>
                    </propertiesGlobal>
                    <jmeterVersion>${jmeter.version}</jmeterVersion>
                    <jmeterExtensions>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-extras:1.4.0</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-standard:1.4.0</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-autostop:0.1</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-casutg:2.9</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter:0.6</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-csvars:0.1</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-functions:2.1</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-manager:1.3</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-perfmon:2.1</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-prmctl:0.4</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-tst:2.5</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-webdriver:3.1</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-dummy:0.4</artifact>
                        <artifact>com.blazemeter:jmeter-parallel:0.9</artifact>
                        <artifactItem>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-manager:1.3</artifactItem>
                        <artifactItem>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-json:2.6</artifactItem>
                    </jmeterExtensions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**JMeter Master Yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: distributed-jmeter-master
  namespace: perf-platform
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: distributed-jmeter-master

spec:
  containers:
    - name: distributed-jmeter-master
      image: maven:3.8.3-jdk-11-openj9
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      command:
        - cat
      tty: true
      resources:
        requests:
          memory: "1024Mi"
          cpu: "100m"
        limits:
          memory: "2048Mi"
          cpu: "200m"
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /root/.m2
          name: m2-volume

    - name: kubehelm
      image: dtzar/helm-kubectl:3.7.0
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      command:
        - cat
      tty: true
      resources:
        requests:
          memory: "256Mi"
          cpu: "100m"
        limits:
          memory: "512Mi"
          cpu: "200m"
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /root/.config
          name: helm-volume
  volumes:
    - name: m2-volume
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: m2-pvc

    - name: helm-volume
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: helm-pvc
```

**JMeter Slave Yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.dep.name }}
  namespace: perf-platform
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ .Values.dep.name }}

spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.slave.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ .Values.dep.name }}

  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ .Values.dep.name }}

    spec:
      containers:
      - name: distributed-jmeter-slave
        image: "{{ .Values.slave.image }}:{{ .Values.slave.tag }}"
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.slave.pullPolicy }}                 
        env:
        - name: MODE
          value: "slave-mode"            
        - name: XMS_VALUE
          value: "{{ .Values.slave.heap.xms.memory }}"
        - name: XMX_VALUE
          value: "{{ .Values.slave.heap.xmx.memory }}"
        args: ["$(MODE)","$(XMS_VALUE)", "$(XMX_VALUE)"]
        ports:
          - containerPort: 50000
          - containerPort: 1099        
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "{{ .Values.slave.res.req.mem }}"
            cpu: "{{ .Values.slave.res.req.cpu }}"
          limits:
            memory: "{{ .Values.slave.res.lim.mem }}"
            cpu: "{{ .Values.slave.res.lim.cpu }}"
```

**JMeter Slave Values Yaml File**

```
#JMeter Slave Configuration
dep:
  name: distributed-jmeter
slave:
  replicaCount: 2
  image: sjay8691/jmeter-all-plugins-slave
  tag: 5.2.1_jdk11_v1
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  res:
    req:
      mem: "1024Mi"
      cpu: "100m"
    lim:
      mem: "1024Mi"
      cpu: "100m"
  heap:
    xms1:
      memory: 512M
    xms2:
      memory: 512M
```

**Jenkins Pipeline**

```
pipeline {
    agent{
        kubernetes {
            yamlFile 'JMeter-master-pod.yaml'
        }
    }

    environment {
        JOBNAME = "jmeter-perf"
    }

    parameters {
        //Project onboarding - Set JMeter Parameters
        string(name: 'jmxFile', description: 'scriptName', defaultValue: "testDemoScript")
        string(name: 'protocol', description: 'protocol', defaultValue: "https")
        string(name: 'host', description: 'host', defaultValue: "catfact.ninja")
        string(name: 'basePath', description: 'basePath', defaultValue: "/breeds?limit=")
        string(name: 'testDataFile', description: 'testDataFile', defaultValue: "testData.csv")
    }

    stages {
        stage ('Deploy JMeter Master-Slave Slaves'){
            steps{
                container ('kubehelm') {
                    sh 'echo =========================================================== Start deploying JMeter [Slave] Pods ==========================================================='                   
                    sh 'helm repo update'
                    sh 'helm install --wait jmeter-${JOBNAME}-${BUILD_NUMBER} --set dep.name=jmeter-distributed-slave-${JOBNAME}-${BUILD_NUMBER} custom/10-distributed-jmeter -f JMeter-slave-pods.yaml'                  
                    sh 'kubectl wait --for=condition=ready pods -l app.kubernetes.io/name=jmeter-distributed-slave-${JOBNAME}-${BUILD_NUMBER} -n perf-platform --timeout=90s'
                    sh 'echo =========================================================== Completed deploying JMeter [Master - Slave] Nodes ==========================================================='
                }
            }
        }

        stage ('Get Slave Pods IP Addresses') {
            steps {
                container ('kubehelm') {
                    sh 'echo =========================================================== Start searching JMeter [Slave] IP Addresses ==========================================================='
                    script {
                        env.jenkinsSlaveNodes = sh(returnStdout: true, script:'kubectl get pods -l app.kubernetes.io/name=jmeter-distributed-slave-${JOBNAME}-${BUILD_NUMBER} -n perf-platform -o jsonpath=\'{.items[*].status.podIP}\' | tr \' \' \',\'')
                    }
                    sh "echo =========================================================================================================="
                    sh "echo Slave IP Details : [${env.jenkinsSlaveNodes}]"
                    sh "echo =========================================================================================================="
                    sh 'echo =============================================s============== Finish searching JMeter [Slave] IP Addresses ==========================================================='
                }
            }
        }

        stage ('Copy Test Data Files') {
            steps {
                container ('kubehelm') {
                    sh 'echo =========================================================== Start copying Test Data Files into JMeter [Slave] Pods ==========================================================='
                    script {
                        env.podNames = sh(returnStdout: true, script:'kubectl get pods -l app.kubernetes.io/name=jmeter-distributed-slave-${JOBNAME}-${BUILD_NUMBER} -n perf-platform -o jsonpath=\'{.items[*].metadata.name}\' | tr \' \' \',\'')
                    }

                    sh '''#!/bin/bash
                        IFS=',' read -r -a podList <<< "$podNames"
                        for pod in "${podList[@]}"
                        do
                            echo "================================================================================================"
                            echo "Copying data files to : $pod [POD]"
                            kubectl cp ./src/test/data perf-platform/$pod:./bin/data
                            echo "================================================================================================"
                        done
                    '''

                    sh "echo Slave Pod Names : ${env.podNames}"
                    sh 'echo =========================================================== Finish Copying Test Data Files into JMeter [Slave] Pods ==========================================================='
                }
            }
        }

        stage ('Execute JMeter Performance Test') {
            steps {
                container ('distributed-jmeter-master') {
                    sh 'echo =========================================================== Start JMeter Performance Test Execution ==========================================================='
                    sh '''
                        mvn clean install -DjenkinsSlaveNodes=${jenkinsSlaveNodes} -DjmxFile=${jmxFile} -Dprotocol=${protocol} \
                        -Dhost=${host} -DbasePath=${basePath} -DtestDataFile=${testDataFile} \
                    '''
                    sh 'echo =========================================================== Completed JMeter Performance Test Execution ==========================================================='
                }
            }
        }

        stage ('Publish JMeter Test Results') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo =========================================================== Start publishing JMeter Performance Test Results ==========================================================='
                sh "echo Present Working Directory : pwd"
                perfReport 'target/jmeter/results/*.csv'
                sh 'echo =========================================================== Finish publishing JMeter Performance Test Results ==========================================================='
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        always {
            sh 'echo =========================================================== Publishing JMeter Log ==========================================================='

            publishHTML (target : [
                    allowMissing: false,
                    alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true,
                    keepAll: true,
                    reportDir: "target/jmeter/logs/",
                    reportFiles: "${jmxFile}.jmx.log",
                    reportName: 'JMeter Log File']
                )

            sh 'echo =========================================================== Finish publishing JMeter Log ==========================================================='

            container ('kubehelm') {
                sh 'echo =========================================================== Start erasing JMeter [Slave] Pods ==========================================================='
                sh 'helm uninstall jmeter-${JOBNAME}-${BUILD_NUMBER}'
                sh 'kubectl wait --for=delete pods -l app.kubernetes.io/name=jmeter-distributed-slave-${JOBNAME}-${BUILD_NUMBER} -n perf-platform --timeout=90s'
                sh 'echo =========================================================== Finish erasing JMeter [Master - Slave] Nodes ==========================================================='
            }

            archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'target/**', fingerprint: true
        }
    }
}
```

**Jenkins Log**

```
    Downloading dependencies: true
    [INFO] Configuring JMeter properties...
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:copy-resources (copy-test-data-1) @ perf-onboard ---
    [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
    [INFO] Using 'null' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
    [INFO] Copying 1 resource
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- jmeter-maven-plugin:3.0.0:jmeter (jmeter-tests) @ perf-onboard ---
    [INFO]  
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO]  P E R F O R M A N C E    T E S T S
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO]  
    [INFO] Will generate HTML report in /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/jmeter-perf-dynamic-slaves/target/jmeter/reports/testDemoScript
    [INFO] Executing test: testDemoScript.jmx
    [INFO] Arguments for forked JMeter JVM: [java, -Xms1024M, -Xmx1024M, -Xprof, -Xfuture, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -jar, ApacheJMeter-5.2.1.jar, -d, /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/jmeter-perf-dynamic-slaves/target/2243f4e2-f010-44d4-96bd-da99fa32fdaa/jmeter, -e, -j, /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/jmeter-perf-dynamic-slaves/target/jmeter/logs/testDemoScript.jmx.log, -l, /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/jmeter-perf-dynamic-slaves/target/jmeter/results/20211008-testDemoScript.csv, -n, -o, /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/jmeter-perf-dynamic-slaves/target/jmeter/reports/testDemoScript, -r, -t, /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/jmeter-perf-dynamic-slaves/target/jmeter/testFiles/testDemoScript.jmx, -R, 10.240.0.215, -Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders, true, -Gprotocol=https, -GbasePath=/breeds?limit=, -Ghost=catfact.ninja]
    [INFO]  
    [INFO] SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
    [INFO] SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/jmeter-perf-dynamic-slaves/target/2243f4e2-f010-44d4-96bd-da99fa32fdaa/jmeter/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.12.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    [INFO] SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/jmeter-perf-dynamic-slaves/target/2243f4e2-f010-44d4-96bd-da99fa32fdaa/jmeter/lib/slf4j-nop-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    [INFO] SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
    [INFO] SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
    [INFO] Oct 08, 2021 9:22:39 AM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1 run
    [INFO] INFO: Created user preferences directory.
    [INFO] WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
    [INFO] WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields (file:/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/jmeter-perf-dynamic-slaves/target/2243f4e2-f010-44d4-96bd-da99fa32fdaa/jmeter/lib/xstream-1.4.11.jar) to field java.util.TreeMap.comparator
    [INFO] WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields
    [INFO] WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
    [INFO] WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
    [INFO] Creating summariser <summary>
    [INFO] Created the tree successfully using /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/jmeter-perf-dynamic-slaves/target/jmeter/testFiles/testDemoScript.jmx
    [INFO] Configuring remote engine: 10.240.0.215
    [INFO] Starting distributed test with remote engines: [10.240.0.215] @ Fri Oct 08 09:22:44 GMT 2021 (1633684964936)
    [INFO] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
    [INFO] Remote engines have been started:[10.240.0.215]
    [INFO] Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
    [INFO] summary =      0 in 00:00:00 = ******/s Avg:     0 Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err:     0 (0.00%)
    [INFO] Tidying up remote @ Fri Oct 08 09:23:06 GMT 2021 (1633684986352)
    [INFO] Error generating the report: java.lang.NullPointerException
    [INFO] ... end of run
    [INFO] Completed Test: /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/jmeter-perf-dynamic-slaves/target/jmeter/testFiles/testDemoScript.jmx
    [INFO]  
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- jmeter-maven-plugin:3.0.0:results (jmeter-check-results) @ perf-onboard ---
    [INFO]  
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] S C A N N I N G    F O R    R E S U L T S
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO]  
    [INFO] Will scan results using format: CSV
    [INFO]  
    [INFO] Parsing results file '/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/jmeter-perf-dynamic-slaves/target/jmeter/results/20211008-testDemoScript.csv' as type: CSV
    [INFO] Number of failures in '20211008-testDemoScript.csv': 0
    [INFO] Number of successes in '20211008-testDemoScript.csv': 0
    [INFO]  
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] P E R F O R M A N C E    T E S T    R E S U L T S
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO]  
    [INFO] Result (.csv) files scanned: 1
    [INFO] Successful requests:         0
    [INFO] Failed requests:             0
    [INFO] Failures:                    NaN% (0.0% accepted)
    [INFO]  
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ perf-onboard ---
    [INFO] Installing /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/jmeter-perf-dynamic-slaves/pom.xml to /root/.m2/repository/groupId/perf-onboard/1.0-SNAPSHOT/perf-onboard-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

**JMeter Log**
    2021-10-08 09:23:12,638 INFO o.a.j.r.d.JsonExporter: Creating statistics for overall
    2021-10-08 09:23:12,638 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Error generating the report: null
    java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.JsonExporter.createStatistic(JsonExporter.java:121) ~[ApacheJMeter_core-5.2.1.jar:5.2.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.JsonExporter.export(JsonExporter.java:71) ~[ApacheJMeter_core-5.2.1.jar:5.2.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.exportData(ReportGenerator.java:377) ~[ApacheJMeter_core-5.2.1.jar:5.2.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.generate(ReportGenerator.java:259) ~[ApacheJMeter_core-5.2.1.jar:5.2.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter$ListenToTest.endTest(JMeter.java:1330) [ApacheJMeter_core-5.2.1.jar:5.2.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter$ListenToTest.lambda$testEnded$0(JMeter.java:1276) [ApacheJMeter_core-5.2.1.jar:5.2.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter$ListenToTest$$Lambda$231/0x000000005814b440.run(Unknown Source) [ApacheJMeter_core-5.2.1.jar:5.2.1]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836) [?:?]
```

**Kubernetes Pods**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHWXe.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are running an old version of the jmeter-maven-plugin (3.0.0), so I suspect you may be suffering from this bug:

https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/issues/356

> When you run:
>
> mvn com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:configure
> com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:remote-server
>
> It appears to work and shows a build success, but in reality it's
> failing silently because there is no default rmi_keystore.jks file in
> the bin directory.

I would suggest increasing your jmeter-maven-plugin version up to the current version (3.5.0 at the time of writing this).

You can see the changes made between 3.0.0 and 3.5.0 by looking at the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md).